# How to include directories recursively in NuSpec file

Tags: recursion, build, nuget, nuspec

I have a folder structure like this in my project...

Project/Folder1/Folder2
-File1
-File2
-File3

Project/Folder1/Folder3
-File4
-File5
-File6

Project/Folder1/Folder4
-File7
-File8

In a NuSpec definition file, how can I tell it to include everything under Folder1 (folders and files recursively)?

Can I just do this or do I need a double ** or what?

```
<file src="Project\Folder1\*.*" target="Project/Folder1" />
```

Comment: Or is it Project\Folder1\\***\\**.* ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the wildcard ** which is [documented on the NuGet web site](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference). From the NuGet docs:

> Using a double wildcard, **, implies a recursive directory search.

```
<file src="tools\**\*.*" exclude="**\*.log" />
<file src="lib\**" target="lib" />
```

Comment: Do I just need the Folder1\\** or do I need to do Folder1\\***\\**.* to get the files to...or will the two asterix's after the Folder1\ be enough to recurse all folders and files?

Comment: Either will work. They have both examples on the NuGet website.

Comment: Now I get this error when CruiseControl and Octopus work together to perform the build using my nuspec file.<br> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\DMG\WorkingDirectory\DMGUmbraco\App_Browsers'<br> My file is like this <files>
        <file src="Project\App_Browsers\\*.*" target="Project\App_Browsers" />. This directory exists! The directory is only level deep, so no need for ** folder recursion.

Comment: IIRC `**.*` will recursively match any file with an extension. `**` will recursively match any file regardless of whether it has an extension.