# Jenkins - how to add additional folder with subfolders, e.g. Images

Tags: jenkins, artifact

I have a web project that Jenkins is building perfectly and pushing to Octopus Deploy.

I now have an additional folder, with subfolders, e.g. Images, which I need to include.

This is not directly part of the .net build and we used to copy it manually afterward.

Do I need a specific plugin which I can use to select the folder to include?
Which plugin?

Where in the build process does this plugin run?

The build and deploy to octopus is done in one step - 
where do I fit in this additional folder to be included in the push to the octopus?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is not directly part of the .net build and we used to copy it manually afterward.

If your Jenkins server can access that addition folder in a shared path, add a pre-build step which, as an "`Executable Windows batch command`" step, would copy that folder into the Jenkins workspace.

[image: https://abc2tech.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/6.png]

No plugin needed here.

Once that is done, you would still need to modify Octopus accordingly, to take into account that new copied folder.
See:

- "[How to add a folder to a nuspec file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24551639/6309)"
- "[How to include directories recursively in NuSpec file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24250484/6309)"

Comment: Hi VonC, this is perfect thanks, I dont see specifically a "pre steps" in my Jenkins instance as in screenshot - maybe its version specific, I can however add a build step, and move it as the first step, which I will now attempt, thank you so much

Comment: As first step in the build, I copied the files to the workspace, but its not included in the build , is there perhaps an additional instruction to mark it to be included in workspace?

Comment: What version of Jenkins are you using?

Comment: 2.32.2 (Current LTS release as at date of post)

Comment: So Im just confirming, with the execute command the files are definitely copied to the workspace folder, it is just when the build and octopus happens then the files are not included in the nuspec file

Comment: @PeterPitLock So do you need something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24551639/6309? Or http://stackoverflow.com/a/24250484/6309?

Comment: Ah ok so its on Octopus, now all the pieces fit, thank you so much VonC

Comment: @PeterPitLock Great! I have included the link in the answer for more visibility.